# Why does subclassing ActiveSupport::TimeZone break its class-level [] operator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With some trepidation, I decided to subclass `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, but I can't get very far because when I call `[]` on my subclass it fails to invoke the superclass's `[]` method. I thought it might have had something to with the fact that the operator overload happens in a class method, so I tried this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.2.1 :001 > class Foo; def Foo.[](f); f; end; end
 => :[] 
2.2.1 :002 > Foo['baz']
 => "baz" 
2.2.1 :003 > class Bar < Foo; end
 => nil 
2.2.1 :004 > Bar['baz']
 => "baz"
```

So that worked exactly as I thought it would. But if that works, why does this fail?

```
2.2.1 :005 > ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/New_York"]
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007f80835c18a8 @name="America/New_York", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/New_York>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1425798000>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: -18000,3600,EDT>>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1446357600>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: -18000,0,EST>>>> 
2.2.1 :006 > class T < ActiveSupport::TimeZone; end
 => nil 
2.2.1 :007 > T["America/New_York"]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a workaround as I already have one (of many possible ones) in place. I'm just trying to understand why the behavior I'm seeing in `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` doesn't match the behavior in `Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [relies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-5B-5D) on calling `[]` on an `@lazy_zones_map` instance variable, which your subclass does not have.

Edit: an example of the behavior:

```
class Foo
  @foo = []  
  def self.[](arg) 
    @foo[arg]
  end  
end

class Bar < Foo
end

Foo[0] #=> nil
Bar[0] #=> undefined method `[]` for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: But shouldn't it be calling `[]` on the superclass, which should in turn load `@lazy_zones_map`?

Comment: It calls the superclass's `[]`, but it does so in the subclass's scope, meaning that only the subclass's instance variables are available; I'll update the answer with an example of the behavior.

Comment: Well, I guess I learned two things about ruby today: 1) subclasses call superclass methods with the subclasses' scope and 2) don't ever subclass anything in ruby.